# determining the maximum capacity of a char pointer in dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, sizeof

First and foremost I want to be clear that this is a past homework assignment that I had but couldn't figure out and that I am still trying to wrap my head around. These are the instructions for the secondary constructor:

**NIUString::NIUString(const char* other)**

> This constructor for the NIUString class should initialize a new `NIUString` object to the C string `other`. The required logic is:
>   Set the string size for the new object to the length of the C string `other`.
>   Set the string capacity for the new object to the string size.
>   If the string capacity is 0, set the string array pointer for the new object to `nullptr`. Otherwise, use the string array pointer for the new object to allocate an array of char. The number of elements in the new string array should be equal to the string capacity.
>   Copy the characters of the C string `other` (up to, but not including the null character) into the string array.

For my output i am supposed to get

> testing second constructor
>   s2: some text
>   s2 size: 9
>   s2 capacity: **9**
>   s2 is not empty

but instead i get...

> testing second constructor
>   s2: some text
>   s2 size: 9
>   s2 capacity: **8**
>   s2 is not empty

After doing research I learned that this is because you can't use `sizeof` on a pointer, as it will only give you the size of the pointer in memory, not the actual size of the string capacity.

Here is my code for the method I wrote

```
//secondary constructor
NIUString::NIUString( const char* other)
{
    Capacity = sizeof(other);
    Size = strlen(other);

    if (Capacity == 0)
    {
        arrayPoint = nullptr;
    }
    else
        arrayPoint = new char[Capacity];
    strcpy(arrayPoint, other);

}
```

Anyway my question is: what is the way in which this can be done? I have been working on this for a bit but haven't found an example similar enough to mine to be of any use. If anyone can guide me in the right direction that would be very useful.

This is the code that I am using to test my method/class; everything else works fine except for the capacity of the array.

```
NIUString s2 = "some text";

cout << "s2: " << s2 << endl;
cout << "s2 size: " << s2.size() << endl;
cout << "s2 capacity: " << s2.capacity() << endl;
cout << "s2 is " << ((s2.empty()) ? "empty\n" : "not empty\n");
cout << endl <<endl << endl;
```

Comment: `sizeof(other);` is invariant: The size of any pointer.

Comment: What is capacity? Isn't the same as size? What are you exactly looking for?

Comment: Are you able to alter the constructor's signature?

Comment: capacity is the max number of elements that can fit into the array whereas size is the actual number of elements in the array

Comment: Im fairly new to c++ so Im not even sure what altering the constructors signature means and therefore probably not something im allowed to do

Comment: The signature is this: `NIUString::NIUString( const char* other)`  Are you able to alter that?  Did you read my answer? I believe that when your home-work instructions say: **Set the string capacity for the new object to the string size** it means to set the capacity of the string to the size (or, length) of the string, because it says just previous to that: **Set the string size for the new object to the length of the C string other.**

Comment: oh okay thanks for the clarification, in that case, no im not able to alter the constructors signature it was a given for the assignment so i kind of have to stick to it. but yeah not that you stated that it was telling me to set the capacity to the string size it definately makes sense now THANKS ALOT seriously i guess my brain is just fried from other classes i couldnt even catch logical errors anymore you guys are awesome.

Comment: I'm glad to clear things up for you.  I know exactly how you feel.  I've done that very same thing many times myself.  Usually your best bet for finding a solution is to take a break and come back to your project later, or to ask for help (as you did here).  Many times it takes a fresh perspective to spot errors.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, do what you want:

1) Capacity autofilled

2) Capacity > size

BUT parameter other MUST NOT allocated using new:

```
template <int _size>
NIUString::NIUString( const char (&other)[_size])
{
    Capacity = _size;
    Size = strlen(other);

    if (Capacity == 0)
    {
        arrayPoint = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        arrayPoint = new char[Capacity];
        strcpy(arrayPoint, other);
    }
}

void main()
{
    char aux[20];// this works
    strcpy(aux, "test");
    NIUString niu(aux);
}
```

Comment: It may not matter, and I don't want to sound like a know-it-all by saying this, but if this is a homework assignment, then chances are that he can't alter the constructor's signature; only how the constructor performs it's task internally.  I may be wrong though, so let's ask him.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sizeof only wok if you have access to the original pointer variable (that have to be static). Normally you use c++ classes for it and dont have to think about it.

I think they want this code:

```
NIUString::NIUString( const char* other)
{
    Size = strlen(other);

    if (Capacity == 0)
    {
        arrayPoint = nullptr;
    }
    if (Capacity <= Size + 1)
    {
        Capacity = Size + 1;
    }
    arrayPoint = new char[Capacity];
    strcpy(arrayPoint, other);

}
```

Comment: I believe that you are using "Capacity" without initializing it.

Comment: I asume hear that Capacity are something like a static variable, although Gerardo's answer is better

Answer (score 0):

**"Set the string capacity for the new object to the string size."**

this is done after

**"Set the string size for the new object to the length of the C string other."**

Therefore:

- **string size** = **string length**
- **string capacity** = **string size**

then:

- **string capacity** = **string length**

I think they are asking for this:

```
//secondary constructor
NIUString::NIUString( const char* other)
{
    Capacity = Size = strlen(other);

    if (Capacity == 0)
    {
        arrayPoint = nullptr;
    }
    else
         arrayPoint = new char[Capacity];

    strcpy(arrayPoint, other);
}
```

Comment: later on in the assignment we have to change the capacity of an object without changing the size. if we set the capacity equal to the string length wouldnt that also change the size later on? im not sure, its an honest question on my part im pretty new to this so im having a hard time with this

Comment: Actually, no it wouldn't.  You see, changing the capacity to a different value is as simple as `Capacity = "the new capacity's value"`.  The "size" would only change with the capacity if you did: `Size = Capacity` or: `Size = "the new capacity's value"`.  You are not **linking** the capacity to the size in any way by simply assigning the the size to the capacity.

Comment: wow that actually does make logical sense to me now, i guess i was confused with the wording of the assignment but not that you laid it out so well it definately seems like that was what was required of the assignment

Comment: Oh yea?  I'm glad I could help you.  If I'm wrong, tell your teachers that some guy on the internet thought that this is what they intended, lol. :P  I have a favor to ask, if this did help you, could you up-vote my answer and maybe accept it as the answer to your question?  That would be great.  If I am wrong about what your teachers meant with their wording, then feel free to down vote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because the end point of the character array (which is dynamically-allocated) is not specified, sizeof will not do what you want.